# VB.NET - Hide form on click outside of the form

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a start menu for my program and I want it to hide() when you click outside it.
The program is fullscreen so that means you're still in the program but just clicking on another form IN the program!

I tried doing it on the event "LostFocus" or whatever it's called, but it did just close again after a second without me doing anything.

Comment: You certain did something: making the form to lose focus. What you are looking for cannot be delivered via events of your form. The whole point of events of a control is reacting to actions on that control; clicking somewhere doesn't belong to this group. You should either rethink how to face the problem or do some research about what is required to get behaviour (global hooks, winapi calls and similar), something not precisely straightforward.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would fit your needs but one option might be to handle the [Deactivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: I've googled like crazy without success. I did try the Deactivate event. Won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This really is harder then it looks unless you use a good programming pattern (like mvc or mvvm)

Withour some central controller you really need to add a event to everything else that says when it's clicked hide the "start menu"

Comment: Well... That would probably work for now then... :( Is it possible to add an event to all controls in a form? By code?